# Multiple Activities in Single Tab Android

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, android-activity

In my application I am trying to open an activity from a button in tab using intent. But instead of opening in the same tab the new activity covers the entire screen and the tabs are no linger visible.. How can I open more than one activity in the same tab..

The following code is of my main class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("OPT").setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroup1Activity.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("EDIT").setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroup2Activity.class)));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
```

The following is the code of TabGroupActivity:

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup{

ArrayList<String> list;
Window window;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(list.equals(null))
    {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}

@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child)
{
    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    int index = list.size() -1;
    if(index < 1)
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    manager.destroyActivity(list.get(index), true);
    list.remove(index);
    index--;
    String lastId = list.get(index);
    Intent in = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
    window = manager.startActivity(lastId, in);
    setContentView(window.getDecorView());
}

public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent)
{
    window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if(window != null)
    {
        list.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        return true;
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    int length = list.size();
    if(length > 1)
    {
        Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(list.get(length - 1));
        current.finish();
    }
}
}
```

The code for TabGroup1Activity the TabGroup2Activity also having the same code:

```
public class TabGroup1Activity extends TabGroupActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startChildActivity("TestClass", new Intent(this,TestClass.class));
}
}
```

Code for the TestClass activity:

```
public class TestClass extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newview);
}
}
```

Please help me is solving my problem..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)..check http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

Comment: I have read that article but its confusing for me thats why I have posted here...

Comment: You need first to understand the concept of fragments, then you can easily use it.. there are too many examples

Comment: you can use fragments inside your tabs, using the button you can hide a fragment and how the other..

Comment: can you provide me a simple tutorial for tabs.. the code that i have posted here from the following link: http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html when I run that application its running fine without an error but when I try to modify the code for a simple tutorial then my application crashes.. I just want to know what i am doing wrong... as there is no error in my code.. but when i try to run my application then force close comes up. But when I run the actual code from the link above then its running fine...