# How to navigate in Tab Application in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, tabview

Hi every one am new to android technology.i would like to ask am having 4 tabs in my project
 in the fourth tab when am clicking on item .it should navigate to new activity also it has to display the remaining 3 tabs  associted with it but when am clicking on it it is displaying the activity individually  not displaying the remaining 3 tabs ..what should i do to overcome from this problem ?can anyone help me thanks in advance ?

Comment: You can refer to the answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12258765/1434631

Comment: Please show us relevant code to get better help!

Comment: @korhan Ozturk thanks for response here is the link you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277947/how-to-navigate-in-tab-application-in-android-with-my-sources-classes can see my activy classes with two classes i mentioned in that the problem is in mymasjedsearch it is diplaying in a separate view but i want it with remaining tabs .also the fourth tab class is fouth activity .

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewStub to simulate differents Activities:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

I did it this way.

Comment: thanks for the response but i couldn't understanding it completely so can u send me other links which may help me in a better way .

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabhost to navigate view.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Answer (score 0):

The idea is implements in the stub the view that simulate your new activity.

```
<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/myStub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/layoutParent"
        android:layout="@layout/new_activity" />
```

when the ViewStub is active hide the actual Layout:

```
myStub = findViewById(R.id.myStub);
myStub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In this moment I can find the new views in the new_activity layout.

Comment: To close:
myStub.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: See this post: http://smarterandroid.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/viewstub-sample.html