# How to navigate in Tab Application in Android? with my sources classes

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, tabview

// The below Fourth  is fourth tab activity in my project so inside it am having few more 
other activites like `MasjidsearchActivity` inside on item .it is displaying as separate activity but i want with remaining tabs

```
package com.hands.iagd.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.R.layout;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Fourth extends Activity {
static  String[] values,Masjeed,Alaram;
    String[]  adjust_calender;
    ListView lv1,lv2,lv3,lv4;
    public static List<String> Calculation_method=new ArrayList<String>();
    int index,index2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fourth);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    lv2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv2);
    lv3=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv3);
    lv4=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv4);

values = new String[] {"Jafari","Karachi","ISNA","MWL","Makkah","Egypt","Custom","Tehran"};
Masjeed = new String[] {"IAGD Masjid"};
Alaram = new String[] {""};



String hijriString="Hijri Calender             "+Adjust_Time.hijriAdjust;
adjust_calender= new String[]{hijriString};

lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,values));
lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


index=First.index;
lv1.setItemChecked(index, true);

lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        index=arg2;
        First.index=arg2;

        System.out.println("index " +index);
    }
});
Masjeed=MasjidsearchActivity.selectedmasjid;
lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Masjeed));
lv2.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

lv2.setItemChecked(index2, true);

lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        index2=arg2;
        First.index2=arg2;

        System.out.println("index " +index2);

        Intent masjid=new Intent(Fourth.this,MasjidsearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(masjid);
    }
});
lv3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,adjust_calender));



lv3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Adjust_Time.sahurORiftar="hijri";

        Intent i=new Intent(Fourth.this,Adjust_Time.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});


}

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String hijriString="Hijri Calender                   "+Adjust_Time.hijriAdjust;
    adjust_calender= new String[]{hijriString};
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,values));
    lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    index=First.index;
    lv1.setItemChecked(index, true);

    lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,Masjeed));
    lv2.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    index2=First.index2;
    lv2.setItemChecked(index2, true);

    lv3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,adjust_calender));

    super.onResume();
}   
}
```

//here is MasjidsearchActivity class

```
package com.hands.iagd.app;


/**
 * ©2010 by androidblogger.ch
 */


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MasjidsearchActivity extends Activity {
    RadioButton rb1 ;
    Button b1,btn;
    EditText edittext;
     ListView mainListView;
     static  String[]  selectedmasjid=new String[] {"IAGD Masjid"};;
    List<Hashtable<String,String>> list1 = new ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>>();
     int textlength = 0;
     ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> text_sort2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    // ArrayList which contains our HashMap's with different objects
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myList;
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myList1;
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> filterList;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.masjidlist);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
       //rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

       /*rb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


System.out.println( "inside radio buttons" );
            }});*/

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                IAGDAPPActivity.settingCurrentTab=3;
         Intent int1 = new Intent(MasjidsearchActivity.this, IAGDAPPActivity.class);
                    startActivity(int1);

            }});



        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_mycontact);
        // Create Hash Map
        myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        myList1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        filterList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();


        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {

        }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int count, int after)
        {

        }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int before, int count)
         {

       textlength = edittext.getText().length();
       text_sort.clear();
       image_sort.clear();
       text_sort2.clear();
       filterList.clear();

       for (int i = 0; i < myList1.size(); i++)
       {
           HashMap<String,Object> maps=new HashMap<String, Object>();
           maps=myList1.get(i);
           String masjidName=maps.get("MosquesNames").toString();
           String cityName=maps.get("MosqueCity").toString();
            List<String> searchStrring = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(masjidName.split(" ")));
            searchStrring.add(masjidName);
            searchStrring.add(cityName);
                for (String s123 : searchStrring) {

                    if (textlength <= s123.length())
                       {

                      if (edittext.getText().toString().
                               equalsIgnoreCase((String) s123.subSequence(0, textlength)))
                               {

                                   filterList.add(maps);
                                   break;
                                }
                }
      /* if (edittext.getText().toString().
       equalsIgnoreCase((String) masjidName.subSequence(0, textlength)))
       {
       //text_sort.add(month[i]);
       //image_sort.add(image[i]);
      // text_sort2.add(desc[i]);
           filterList.add(maps);
        }*/
       }
       }
displayList(filterList);
mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
mainListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);



        System.out.println("****3");      

        }
       });


        // Fill data
       // addDataToList();
        addDBFROMCSV();
        // View
         mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);

        // Adapter
/*        SimpleAdapter aa = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, R.layout.row,
                new String[] {"name", "address", "city", "icon"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.txt_name, R.id.txt_town, R.id.txt_phone, R.id.img_user});
        mainListView.setAdapter(aa);*/

      /*  SimpleAdapter aa = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList1, R.layout.row,
                new String[] {"MosquesNames", "MosqueAddress", "MosqueCity","icon"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.txt_name, R.id.txt_town, R.id.txt_phone, R.id.img_user});
        mainListView.setAdapter(aa);

*/      displayList(myList1);  
        // Listener
mainListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              // Get the HashMap of the clicked item
              HashMap<String, Object> user = myList1.get(position);

              // Get Attribute name of the HashMap
              String name = (String)user.get("MosquesNames");
              selectedmasjid =new String[] {name};

              System.out.println("name:"+selectedmasjid.length);
              // Create new Dialog
              final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MasjidsearchActivity.this);
              dialog.setTitle(" " + name);
              TextView txtDescription = new TextView(MasjidsearchActivity.this);
              txtDescription.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 10);
              txtDescription.setText("Masjid Selected");
              dialog.setContentView(txtDescription);

              dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
              dialog.show();
          }
        });  

    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    CreateMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    return MenuChoice(item);
    }

    private void CreateMenu(Menu menu)
    {


            MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Register with us");
            {
                    mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('a');
                    //mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.image1);
            }
            MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Notify about your Masjid ");
            {
                    mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut('b');
                    //mnu2.setIcon(R.drawable.image2);
            }
            MenuItem mnu3 = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Cancel");
            {
                    mnu3.setAlphabeticShortcut('c');
                    //mnu3.setIcon(R.drawable.image3);
            }
        /*  MenuItem mnu4 = menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Item 4");
            {
                    mnu4.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
            }
            menu.add(0, 4,4, "Item 5");
            menu.add(0, 5,5, "Item 6");
            menu.add(0, 6,6, "Item 7");*/
    }
    private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item)
    {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case 0:
                Intent i=new Intent(MasjidsearchActivity.this,Register.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Notify",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case 1:
                Intent i1=new Intent(MasjidsearchActivity.this,masjidnotify.class);
                startActivity(i1);

                //Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Register",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case 2:
                //Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            /*case 3:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 4",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;*/
        /*  case 4:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 5",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case 5:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 6",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case 6:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 7",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;*/
            }
            return false;

    }
    private void displayList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myLists) {
          SimpleAdapter aa = new SimpleAdapter(this, myLists, R.layout.row,
                  new String[] {"MosquesNames", "MosqueAddress", "MosqueCity","icon"}, 
                  new int[] {R.id.txt_name, R.id.txt_town, R.id.txt_phone, R.id.img_user});
          mainListView.setAdapter(aa);
          mainListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    }

    private void addDBFROMCSV()
    {
         InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource
         (R.raw.listofmosquesinusa);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
         (is));
             try {
                ArrayList< String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
                 String line;
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     // do something with "line"
                 // System.out.println("llllll"+line);
                    list.add(line);
                 }
               //  System.out.println("llllll"+list);
                 ArrayList<List<String>> arrayList=new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                 for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                 {
                    String s1=list.get(i);
                    List<String> list12 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s1.split("123456COLUMNDEVIDER")));
                 // System.out.println("List1 is "+list1);
                 // System.out.println("List size is "+list1.size());
                 arrayList.add(list12); 

                 }



                 ArrayList<List<String>> updatedList =new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                 for(int k=0;k<arrayList.size();k++)
                 {
                     List<String> l111=new ArrayList<String>();
                     List<String> l1=new ArrayList<String>();
                     l1=arrayList.get(k);

                     for(int j=0;j<l1.size();j++)
                     {

                        String sss1=l1.get(j);
                        if(sss1.length()<2)
                        {
                            l111.add(" ");
                        //  System.out.println("Values in empty"+sss1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            char c1=sss1.charAt(0);
                            if(c1==',' )
                            {
                                sss1=sss1.substring(1);
                            }
                            c1=sss1.charAt(sss1.length()-1);
                            if(c1==',' )
                            {
                                sss1=sss1.substring(0,sss1.lastIndexOf(","));
                            }   
                            l111.add(sss1);
                            //System.out.println("Values in "+sss1);                
                        }
                     }
                     updatedList.add(l111);
                 }
                 System.out.println("updated list"+updatedList);
             ArrayList<String> tblList=new ArrayList<String>();
             for(int i=0;i<updatedList.size();i++)
             {
             List<String> oneList=updatedList.get(i);
             String x1=oneList.get(0);
             String x2=oneList.get(1);
             String x3=oneList.get(2);
             String x4=oneList.get(3);
             String x5=oneList.get(4);
             String x6=oneList.get(5);
             String x7=oneList.get(6);
             String x8=oneList.get(7);
             String x9=oneList.get(8);
             String x10=oneList.get(9);
           //  String x11=oneList.get(10);
                 Hashtable<String, String> hm = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                hm.put("Sno", x1);
                hm.put("MosquesNames", x2);
                hm.put("MosqueAddress", x3);
                hm.put("MosqueCity", x4);
                hm.put("Mosquestate", x5);
                hm.put("Mosquezip", x6);
                hm.put("Mosquecountry", x7);
                hm.put("Mosquephn1", x8);
                hm.put("Mosquephn2", x9);
                hm.put("Mosquephn3", x10);
                //hm.put("Mosquephn3", x10);
             //     hm.put("icon", R.drawable.images);
                HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map1.put("Sno", x1);
                map1.put("MosquesNames", x2);
                map1.put("MosqueAddress", x3);
                map1.put("MosqueCity", x4);
                map1.put("Mosquestate", x5);
                map1.put("Mosquezip", x6);
                map1.put("Mosquecountry", x7);
                map1.put("Mosquephn1", x8);
                map1.put("Mosquephn2", x9);
            map1.put("Mosquephn3", x10);
                map1.put("icon", R.drawable.images);
                myList1.add(map1);
              //    list1.add(hm) ;

              //    add=hm.get("MosquesNames")+"  "+hm.get("MosqueAddress")+" "+hm.get("MosqueCity");
             //tblList.add(add);

             }

                    System.out.println("new:"+myList1);
             }


             catch (IOException ex) {
                 // handle exception
             }
             finally {
                 try {
                     is.close();
                 }
                 catch (IOException e) {
                     // handle exception
                 }
             }


    }
    /**
     * This method is used, to fill data into our List
     */

    private void addDataToList(){
        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map1.put("icon", R.drawable.images);
        map1.put("name", "Al-Masjidul Al-Kaa'Bah");
        map1.put("address", "691 Idlewild Circle - Suite H");
        map1.put("city", "Birmingham, Alabama");

        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map2.put("icon",R.drawable.images);
        map2.put("name", "Al-Masjidul Al-Kaa'Bah ");
        map2.put("address", "691 Idlewild Circle - Suite H");
        map2.put("city", "Birmingham, Alabama");

        HashMap<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map3.put("icon", R.drawable.images);
        map3.put("name", "Birmingham Islamic Society");
        map3.put("address", "  ");
        map3.put("city", "Birmingham, Alabama");

        HashMap<String, Object> map4 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map4.put("icon", R.drawable.images);
        map4.put("name", "Birmingham Mosque");
        map4.put("address","1534 19th Street");
        map4.put("city", "Birmingham, Alabama");

        HashMap<String, Object> map5 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map5.put("icon", R.drawable.images);
        map5.put("name", "Masjid Al-Quran");
        map5.put("address", " ");
        map5.put("city", "Birmingham, Alabama");

        myList.add(map1);
        myList.add(map2);
        myList.add(map3);
        myList.add(map4);
        myList.add(map5);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1/ too long. 2/ format your code. 3/ what was your question again?

Comment: @njzk2 i would like to ask am having 4 tabs in my project in the fourth tab when am clicking on item .it should navigate to new activity also it has to display the remaining 3 tabs associted with it but when am clicking on it it is displaying the activity individually not displaying the remaining 3 tabs ..what should i do to overcome from this problem ?can anyone help me thanks in advance ?